# How to get the running total pay and running balance in mysql?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a following Records below...

```
+----+-------+------------+
| ID | token | actual_pay |
+----+-------+------------+
|  1 | 500   | 900        |
|  2 | 400   | 900        |
|  3 | 300   | 900        |
|  4 | 600   | 900        |
|  5 | 800   | 900        |
|  6 | 700   | 900        |
|  7 | 400   | 900        |
|  8 | 450   | 900        |
|  9 | 900   | 900        |
| 10 | 800   | 900        |
| 11 | 700   | 900        |
| 12 | 800   | 850        |
+----+-------+------------+
```

My problem is how to get the running total pay and running balance. 
My formula are the following: 
Legend:
RTP = Running Total Pay
BAL = Running Balance
TK = Token
PAY = Actual Pay

Formula:
1. On 1st ID, the value of TK must be default value of RTP, so the formula of BAL would be: 
BAL=PAY-TK 
2. While on the 2nd to the 12th ID, the formula would be: 
RTP=BAL+PAY 
BAL=RTP-TK

So the output will be like this one...

```
+----+-----+-----+------+------+
| ID | TK  | PAY | RTP  | BAL  |
+----+-----+-----+------+------+
|  1 | 500 | 900 | 500  | 400  |
|  2 | 400 | 900 | 1300 | 900  |
|  3 | 300 | 900 | 1800 | 1500 |
|  4 | 600 | 900 | 2400 | 1800 |
|  5 | 800 | 900 | 2700 | 1900 |
|  6 | 700 | 900 | 2800 | 2100 |
|  7 | 400 | 900 | 3000 | 2600 |
|  8 | 450 | 900 | 3500 | 3050 |
|  9 | 900 | 900 | 3950 | 3050 |
| 10 | 800 | 900 | 3950 | 3150 |
| 11 | 700 | 900 | 4050 | 3350 |
| 12 | 800 | 850 | 4200 | 3400 |
+----+-----+-----+------+------+
```

Comment: It's not a duplicate... kindly review the question...

Comment: This isn't a duplicate.  The rules are different from a typical running total.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just copied and pasted your formula:

```
select id, token tk, actual_pay pay,
  if(@rtp is null, @rtp:=token, @rtp:=@bal+actual_pay) rtp,
  if(@bal is null, @bal:=actual_pay-token, @bal:=@rtp-token) bal
from records a
join (select @rtp:=null, @bal:=null) b
;
```

[fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/2a954f/6)

Comment: @xenonleaux, which one?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24523109/how-to-get-the-new-running-balance-from-existing-balance